# DotNet Google API Authentication Issue

Tags: .net, google-api, prediction, service-accounts

I'm trying to run the Google Prediction API for .Net (VB.Net) and I'm facing some problems.
Somebody have a code example using Service Account Key Authentication?

My code:

```
Dim myService As New PredictionService()
Dim myInput As New Data.Input()
Dim myInputData As New Data.Input.InputData()
Dim myListParameters As New List(Of Object)

myListParameters.Add("myInfo")
myInputData.CsvInstance = myListParameters
myInput.InputValue = myInputData

Dim myRequest As TrainedmodelsResource.PredictRequest = _
myService.Trainedmodels.Predict(myInput, "myProject", "myModel")

myRequest.OauthToken = "How can I get the OauthToken?"
myRequest.Key = "My API Key"

Dim myResponse = myRequest.Execute()
```

When I ran the above code I get the response:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Login Required [401]
Errors [
    Message[Login Required] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

So, in google console I created a service account key and I did the download of json file and try to execute the code bellow to generate the authToken

```
Dim prediction As New PredictionService
Dim service = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData( _
New StreamReader("the path of jsonFile").BaseStream)
Dim auth As String = Await service.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()
```

When I ran this code, a get the Error:
"invalid_scope", "Empty or missing scope not allowed.", Uri:""

The Scope Property from my variable service is Empty and it is ReadOnly. So I dont know how to proceed.

Someboby can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I created a new Service Account Key on Google Console, but now with P12 Instead the JsonFile.

Here's the code:

```
Private Async Function GetToken() As Task(Of String)

    Dim service_email = "your e-mail service accout xxxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

    Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2("yourCertificatePath.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

    Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(service_email) With {
         .Scopes = New String() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction"}
    }.FromCertificate(certificate))

    credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Wait()

    Return credential.Token.AccessToken

End Function
```

Now I'm facing another problem, but I'll create a new topic.

Thanks!